# How could I manage Google Adsense to approve my Web App? It keeps denying it

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

Google adsense keeps denying my app from having ads, because of an "insufficient content" issue.

I manage a Web Application that allows the users to set Youtube Videos as Alarm Clocks. It includes an in-site Youtube search to retrieve videos from user queries and lists the users alarms.

The site has a good traffic (500 users per day), is currently promoted by Google in Google Chrome Webstore, and the ajax requests are crawlable, following Google's guidelines (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

Although I understand there is not much content,  beyond the user-generated, I really don't what else should I include in the site. Perhaps adding contact and about pages, and maybe another section would increase the navigation. Google argues I need a **"fully launched and functioning site, allowing users to navigate throughout your site with a menu, sitemap, or appropiate links"**. They also ask for "full sentences or paragraphs"

Isn't a Google Adsense solutions for Web Applications? Would all the web-apps have to include useless navigable subpages?

Answer (score 2):

Adsense is a contextual ad network. That means it displays ads based on the website's **textual** content. The adsense bot cannot make sense of images or videos only text. So you **need** textual content on your site for it to deliver related ads.

Google itself struggles to monetize videos. AFAIK youtube is not profitable either.

So you need to look at alternative ad networks other than adsense. Maybe banner ad networks that pay on a CPM basis.

BTW if you follow Andrew's advice you may get your site into adsense but you won't earn much. Without any relevant textual content to parse all the ads you see will be unrelated to your site's content and hence they will deliver poor revenue. There is also the risk of getting your adsense account disabled since Google has already rejected your site.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only for your first site or else I was grand-fathered in on an old policy without my knowledge as I don't need any kind of approval when I create a new site and generate ads for it in Adsense.

May be a bit black hat-ish but you could always go on a site like flippa and buy a cheap site that has content and apply with that domain first just so you can get in the door.  Alternatively just go on a forum like forums.digitalpoint.com and buy some articles and toss them on a new site and apply with that.